# How to collapse opened TableView section when other section tapped

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using CollapsibleTableView section, it's working everything is okay about it. But I need to collapse already opened section when other not opened section tapped.

```
  struct CustomCell {
     var opened = Bool()
     var title = String()
     var sectionData = [String]()
  }

 // I'm using this part inside TableView didSelectForRowAt
 if tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened {
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = false
            let section = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(section, with: .none)
        } else {
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = true
            let section = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(section, with: .none)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code of my project

```
 @objc private func sectionTapped(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Tapped",recognizer.view?.tag)

        guard let tag = recognizer.view?.tag else {
            return
        }

        // We have already open section 
        if let currentExpandedTag = self.sectionExpanded {

            //collapse 
            if tag == currentExpandedTag {
                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.sectionExpanded = nil

                self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: tag), with: .fade)
                self.tableView.endUpdates()
            } else {
                // Collapse current and expand other
                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: currentExpandedTag), with: .fade)

                self.sectionExpanded = tag
                self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: tag), with: .fade)

                self.tableView.endUpdates()
                self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: tag), at: .top, animated: true)

            }
        } else {
            // Nothing expanded
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.sectionExpanded = tag

            self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: tag), with: .fade)


            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }

    }
```

**Explanation :**

1) In `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` Method I have set tag to content header view and added **Tap gesture**

2) I have property in view controller     `var sectionExpanded:Int?` Which keeps track of which section expanded

3) Other code is self explanatory

4)  In  `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int`  Method  I have checked following

```
   if let sectionExpanded = self.sectionExpanded, section == sectionExpanded {
        return subItemCount // From your array 
    }
    return 0
```